# Azure mobile services backend "mssql" object not found

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to create a custom API for Azure Mobile Services that does a Transact-SQL command on the table. According to the docs I should be able to use an object called `'mssql'` to do this (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554212.aspx). However, the object does not seem to exist and my backend script always fails with error 500 (internal server error).  Does this object not exist in custom API backend scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use that object in a custom API, you should access it via the `request` object passed to the API:

```
exports.get = function(request, response) {
    var mssql = request.services.mssql;
    mssql.query('select GETDATE() from myTable', {
        success: function(results) {
            response.send(200, { serverTime: results[0] });
        }
    });
}
```